# Substitute a varible list in a code snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, sparklines

I'm not really js expert, so I have the following situation:
The code below draw sparklines (jQuery sparklines), however, I have more than 400 variables for it, and I don't think it is smart to repeat that code 400 times, how to substitute the variable name (var1) in this code with a variable contains all the names?

```
 $('#sparkline_var1_x').sparkline(var1, {
    type: "bar",
barColor: '#fc3944',
        tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} {{value}}',
tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': labels
    }
});
```

for example, I have a variable called `var_all` and contains `var1, var2, ..., var400`, how to substitute it to be like this

```
 $('#sparkline_$var_all_x').sparkline($var_all, {
    type: "bar",
barColor: '#fc3944',
        tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} {{value}}',
tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': labels
    }
});
```

So it is just written once.
Now the above code may make no sense for JS developer, but just to get the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `var_all` into an array containing the `var#` variables, eg:

```
const varAll = [var1, var2, var3, ...]
```

(preferably without retaining the individual `var1` variables, they're repetitive)

Then iterate over the array, using the value and the index to identify which `#sparkline_var1_x` to use:

```
varAll.forEach((val, i) => {
  $(`#sparkline_var${i + i}_x`).sparkline(val, {
    type: "bar",
      barColor: '#fc3944',
      tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} {{value}}',
      tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': labels
      }
  });
});
```

But numeric-indexed IDs are quite a code smell. Elements with an ID should indicate something *completely unique* in a document, which only exist once. Consider using classes instead, eg `sparkline`:

```
const sparklines = $('.sparklines');
varAll.forEach((val, i) => {
  $(sparklines[i]).sparkline(val, {
    type: "bar",
      barColor: '#fc3944',
      tooltipFormat: '{{offset:offset}} {{value}}',
      tooltipValueLookups: {
        'offset': labels
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! two questions: **1-** if my variables aren't numerical indexed, and I stored all of them in `varAll`, can I write it like this _$(`#sparkline_${varAll}_x`)_? . **2-** How about `val` in `sparkline(val`, can I replace it with `varAll` directly so it will be `sparkline(varAll`? as I need both to be the same variable as I wrote in the example in the question. Thanks

Comment: If they aren't numerical, use an object instead of an array, then use the object's keys instead of the array index to identify which `_var` to pass to `$`. *can I replace it with varAll directly so it will be sparkline(varAll* Don't think so, since you need to pass different parameters to each one.